# string to args(string[])

Tags: c#

I'm creating a console application that will receive parameters like `get "www.site.com" -i -a`.
But this args will not be the Main constructor args parameter, I will receive it from `Console.ReadLine()`.
So how can I parse the string that I will receive from console into string[] args correct?
I need to assume that client can write something like `get "www.google.com www.yahoo.com" -i -a`, so my args should be:

1. get
2. "www.google.com www.yahoo.com"
3. -i
4. -a

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Please elaborate on how the `-i` and `-a` are expected to get from inside the quotation marks to their outside.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I update the question to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression like

```
([^" ][^ ]*)|("[^"]*")
```

to match the single strings. So something like

```
var r = new Regex("([^\" ][^ ]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")");
var s = Console.ReadLine();
var result = r.Matches(s).OfType<Match>().Select(m=>m.Value).ToArray();
```

should get you the desired array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to do simple lexical analysis, like this:

```
var s = @"get ""www.google.com www.yahoo.com"" -i -a";
var ms = Regex.Matches(s, "(-?\\w+)|\"([^\"]*)\"");
foreach (Match m in ms) {
    if (m.Groups[1].ToString() != "") {
         Console.WriteLine("Flag/Command: {0}", m.Groups[1]);
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Quoted string: '{0}'", m.Groups[2]);
    }
}
```

The heart of this solution is the following regular expression (quotes are un-escaped for readability):

```
(-?\\w+)|"([^"]*)"
```

It has two *capturing groups* - the first one for flags or commands, and the second one (after the pipe symbol '|') for quoted strings. Once the expression "sees" a quotation mark, it captures everything until the closing quote is found. The capturing group strips both quotes by keeping them outside the parentheses.

[Link to ideone.](http://ideone.com/104UZg)

Comment: The first group will not capture arguments with special chars. So an argument like "-?" (without quotes) wouldn't be recognized.

Comment: @MartinStettner The expression there is to give the OP a starting point to build his solution. It provides a skeleton; adding more details to it should be simple.

Comment: @MuriloKunze try entering `get -?`, I guess, the "-?" argument will not be recognized.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If someone reads and tries this without knowing much about regular expressions (somone who knows wouldn't need to read this after all :) ), he might have a hard time to find out why it will not work on arbitrary arguments. So I just wanted to give another hint, no offense :)

Comment: @MuriloKunze If you would like other characters to be recognized as arguments, replace `\\w` with `[^\"\\s]`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I was using the regex of MartinStettner when I test LOL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `TextFieldParser` class from Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

```
string arguments = Console.ReadLine();
TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(arguments));
parser.Delimiters = new[] { " " };
parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
string[] parsedArguments = parser.ReadFields();
```